# how to prevent SQL Injection in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc, sql-injection, prepared-statement

Just last week, I was doing some PHP stuff. I worked a little solution to prevent SQL injections. PHP has been always my man, it has readily 3 solutions for use (maybe more). One is to enable "magic queries" using `stripslashes()` function. Another one (the recommended) is to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` function. 
That simple and my problem is solved. However, things don't seem to be that simple when it comes to JSP. I searched and didn't find any built-in function to strip slashes or do those sort of things (I believe such functionality can be implemented using basic JAVA functions but...).

Please help me protect my database. I heard about `PreparedStatement`, but really can't get my head around it? (I feel the real meaning of newbieness).

Comment: Which database system are you using?  MySQL?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just use [`PreparedStatement`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead of [`Statement`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html).

I.e. use

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO tbl (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
preparedStatement.setString(1, col1);
preparedStatement.setString(2, col2);
preparedStatement.setString(3, col3);
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

instead of

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO tbl (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ('" + col1 + "', '" + col2 + "', '" + col3 + "')";
statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.executeUpdate(sql);
```

The `PreparedStatement` also offers convenient setter methods for other types, such as `setInt()`, `setDate()`, `setBinaryStream()`, etcetera.

Please note that this issue is unrelated to JSP. It's related to Java in general. Writing raw Java code in a JSP class is also considered a [poor practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files). Best practice is to create a standalone class which does all the DB interaction tasks on a particular table, which is also called a DAO (Data Access Object) class. You can then import/use this DAO class in a servlet class.

#### See also:

- [Java Tutorials - JDBC Tutorial - PreparedStatement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)
- [Difference between Statement and PreparedStatement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271249/difference-between-statement-and-preparedstatement)
- [how to send a ResultSet object in jsp back to html (javascript)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407861/how-to-send-a-resultset-object-in-jsp-back-to-html-javascript)

Comment: Wow, here is a comment that spreads a ton of information, your comment was very helpful to me, you made it simple, I thank you and it's solved because of you!

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, it was an answer, not a comment. Those tiny things which you see below questions/answers are comments :)

Comment: +1 for the "Java code in JSP is a bad practice" comment.  It seems like such a great idea when you're getting going with JSPs, but oh the pain when you return later to rip out all that non-view related logic.